# Entity Framework. How to get Entity that contains list of same items by GroupId

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a Products table.

```
public class ProductEntity()
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int GroupId {get;set;}
}
```

I want to get all group items within product. So I added list inside of same items inside of my class

```
public class ProductEntity()
    {
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public int GroupId {get;set;}
       public virtual ICollection<ProductEntity> GroupProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

The question is that I cannot set relationship by Fluent API. I am getting error on empty WithMany.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductEntity>()
                .HasMany(x => x.GroupProducts )
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupId);
```

It's a working table and I can't create 3rd table for group relationship. I want to do my task with existing GroupId inside of my Products table. Thanks

Comment: This is a bad design, the GroupProducts should be a query, not the member of the product

Comment: yes I know, but I can't the database schema. :(

Comment: https://medium.com/@dmitry.pavlov/tree-structure-in-ef-core-how-to-configure-a-self-referencing-table-and-use-it-53effad60bf

Comment: AliReza's suggestion doesn't seem to be anything to do with changing the database schema. Why not try something like `context.Products.Where(p => p.GroupId == context.Products.First(pp => pp.ProductId == 1).GroupId)` or `context.Products.Where(p => context.Products.Any(pp => pp.GroupId == p.GroupId && pp.ProductId == 1))`

Comment: I have more than 1000 products and I think it will not be a good solution to call this on every item. I am displaying all products and related products on the same time (same screen).

Comment: In case of Entity Framework it will get all list in one single SQL query, but in this case I will have a performance issue

Comment: Does your db context has a Group entity? Rephrasing, does the database has a Group table?

Comment: How are you going to display more than 1000 products, in any form, in a usable fashion, on a single screen? And why is your query not then just `context.Products.ToList().GroupBy(p => p.GroupId)`?

Comment: Your question needs more clarity; show us the design of the screen you propose so we can use it to decide a strategy.